# Copy 60 most recent values from appended .csv to a new .csv every minute? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, loops, csv, timer

I'd like to extract the 60 most recent values from a .csv file called `MyFile` which is appended with 3 new values in the row below the previous set every minute using a timer function:

```
dlmwrite('MyFile.csv', [MyValue,MyValue2,MyValue3], '-append');
```

Say I have 150 rows of values in `MyFile` after 100 minutes and I want to extract the latest 60 to save to another file called `MyFile2`. The process happens indefinitely because of an endless timer i.e it accumulates data over time so the row size of the MyFile.csv is increasing by 1 every minute. So, 3 columns of data in each row, new row every minute.(Ignore the timer, i'm just showing here that it works and is used to get the new `MyValue`'s) Timer:

```
Period = 60; % Update period in seconds

tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'TimerFcn', 'ThisScript');

start(tim)

stop(tim) 

runtmp = fullfile('MyScriptLocation','MyScript');
run(runtmp);
```

How can I continually copy over the 60 most recent sets of values from the file and store them in `MyFile2`?

Is there a size function I could use for my .csv file so that it fetches the size of the .csv as it grows and then pulls the most recent 60 values added to it?

I feel like this would be the easiest way to do it but i'm still unsure.

Rough pseudocode i'm unsure of (don't think its right):

```
Take size of MyFile
   for k=1:size(MyFile)
          dlmwrite('MyFile2.csv', [MyValue(k),MyValue2(k),MyValue3(k)], '-append');
```

but obviously need code there that says subtract size from each row number so that the correct values are appended to `MyFile2`. Hope i've made this clear. If there aren't 60 rows of values in `MyFile` yet then a text/string message 'N/A' should appear.

edit*: Error received with Horchler's solution:

```
Error in ==>
SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI>SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI_OpeningFcn at
1265
dlmwrite('MyFile2.csv',',',out(max(end-60,1):end));
```

code entered was:

```
out = dlmread('60 mins.csv',',');
dlmwrite('MyFile2.csv',',',out(max(end-60,1):end));
```

Where `'60 mins.csv'` is the name of `MyFile`

Answer (score 1):

There's no real method to get the size/length of a CSV file other than reading in the whole thing. If the first CSV file never grows excessively large you should be able to do something like this:

```
out = dlmread('MyFile.csv',',');
dlmwrite('MyFile2.csv',',',out(max(end-60,1):end));
```

The save the put to the last 60 entries from `'MyFile.csv'` into `'MyFile2.csv'` (it's not clear exactly what you want in the second file). You might also check to see if `textscan` is faster for reading in your data.

Other possibilities are discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/172516) in a related question.

Another option might be to create some dedicated fields in your CSV file where the new size/length gets also updated each time you append new data. Then you you could always read these first and know the current number of elements.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I want in second file. I want the same as the first file (format and content) but only the most recently added 60 rows. I tried your suggestion but got an error (which I will update my thread with). Alternatively, is there any way for me to sum the most recent 60 values of say, column 2 in MyFile and store it as a variable? The reason I am wanting the data in this way is to calculate an average of the value stored in column 2 over 60 minutes but I always need the 60 most recent values to do that. Thanks.